# Is it possible to change the mmIenu width without SASS

Tags: mmenu

Is there any way to change the menu width without using SASS? (I'm running Windows 8.1, and I can't tell you how much I don't want to install Ruby...)

I can change the width of the menu contents, but the mmslideout moves to the wrong place.

Comment: You can use Koala for instance http://koala-app.com/ to compile SASS. It can monitor your files, compile them automatically etc... Saves me a lot of time and I believe you don't need ruby at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but koala doesn't seem to play nice with Win 8.1.

Comment: I'm using Koala on 8.1 without a single issue...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can override the `.mm-menu` class in your custom css file for the `min-width`, `max-width` properties.

Regarding SASS compilation, i would recommend using [Libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass), it's an efficient C/C++ port of the Sass CSS precompiler.

Comment: Thanks for your response...yes, I can override the css, but only the list of items change, the menu slides out to the wrong position, so I get this wide well, with a narrow menu in it, and since I'm also changing the color of the menu, it looks really odd.

Answer (score 0):

[Sassy Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d) seems a pretty clean VSIX, and worked for me. (Eventually ;). I'm new to SASS.)